# Exclude elements from vector based on regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, r

I have some data which I want to clean up using a regular expression in R.

It is easy to find how to get elements that contain certain patterns, or do not contain certain words (strings), but I can't find out how to do this for excluding cells containing a pattern.

**How could I use a general function to only keep those elements from a vector which do not contain *PATTERN*?**

I prefer not to give an example, as this might lead people to answer using other (though usually nice) ways than the intended one: excluding based on a regular expression. Here goes anyway:

How to exclude all the elements that contain any of the following characters:
`'pyfgcrl`

```
vector <- c("Cecilia", "Cecily", "Cecily's", "Cedric", "Cedric's", "Celebes", 
            "Celebes's", "Celeste", "Celeste's", "Celia", "Celia's", "Celina")
```

The result would be an empty vector in this case.

Comment: `vector[!grepl("['pyfgcrl]", vector)]`

Comment: @kohske That's it. Care to write an answer about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: From the comments, and with a little testing, one would find that my suggestion wasn't correct.

Here are two correct solutions:

```
vector[!grepl("['pyfgcrl]", vector)]                    ## kohske
grep("['pyfgcrl]", vector, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE) ## flodel
```

If either of them wants to re-post and accept credit for their answer, I'm more than happy to delete mine here.

---

#### Explanation

The general function that you are looking for is `grepl`. From the help file for `grepl`:

> `grepl` returns a logical vector (match or not for each element of `x`).

Additionally, you should read the help page for `regex` which describes what *character classes* are. In this case, you create a character class `['pyfgcrl]`, which says to look for any character in the square brackets. You can then negate this with `!`.

So, up to this point, we have something that looks like:

```
!grepl("['pyfgcrl]", vector)
```

To get what you are looking for, you subset as usual.

```
vector[!grepl("['pyfgcrl]", vector)]
```

---

For the second solution, offered by @flodel, `grep` by default returns the *position* where a match is made, and the `value = TRUE` argument lets you return the actual string value instead. `invert = TRUE` means to return the values that were *not* matched.

Comment: `^['pyfgcrl]` means: look for any string *starting* with a character of `'pyfgcrl` (for excluding you have to use `[^'pyfgrcl]`). That's why it fails when adding `bzz`. @flodel's `grepl("['pyfgcrl]", vector, invert=TRUE)` is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, it should have been: `[^'pyfgcrl]`. But even that doesn't work in R. It gives true for everything.

Comment: @Arun, that was actually my intent. Any idea why it doesn't work in R?

Comment: @sgibb, thanks. That was my intent. As Arun points out, even `[^'pyfgrcl]` doesn't work here. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I guess probably because `grep` has an `invert` argument explicitly.. (and so it was never intended to be..)? Not sure though. Will check it a bit more in detail and write back.

Comment: @Arun, perhaps, but `grepl` doesn't. Perhaps it is just more "R" to use `!` with logical vectors?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, hmm, true. `gregexpr` spots it right though. `gregexpr("[^c]", c("abc", "dec", "def"))`

Comment: It seems to me like `grepl("[^c]", x)` (where `x <- c("abc", "dec", "def")`) is doing `!grepl("^c", x)` instead of `!grepl("c", x)`.

Comment: @Arun, interesting tests. That is, indeed some strange behavior. I honestly don't know what to make of all of it....

Comment: @Arun `[^'pyfgcrl]` returns `TRUE` because all of those strings have characters other those in them.  Look at the output of `grepl("[^abc]", x)` or `grepl("[^abcde]", x)`

Comment: @GSee, yes indeed. That explains it. Thanks. That also explains the `gregexpr` output.