# In R: exclude strings if not all characters is part of a character class

Tags: regex, r

In [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511548/exclude-elements-from-vector-based-on-regular-expression-pattern) a solution is shown how one can use a regex to keep only those elements from a vector which do not contain a pattern.
But how can we using R's grep familiy exclude strings from a vector if a single character is not part of some character class ? For instance:

```
s <- c("ab", "bbc", "cda")
```

Want to use regex to exclude element not described by characters in the character class [abc] ? I.e. we want to exclude "cda" (since it contains a "d") and get:

```
[1] "ab"  "bbc"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the anchors `^` and `$` to ensure that no other characters will match. Combined with the `+` meta-character, if any other token appears in the string, the match will fail.

```
grep("^[abc]+$", s, value = TRUE)
#[1] "ab"  "bbc"
```

Comment: Nice. So the anchors tells that no other than [abc] (+ = as many time as possible) will match after and before ?

Comment: They mark the beginning and the end of the string. If I use the pattern `"^a"`, I will only get a match when a is at the beginning. So we take that logic further. With `"^a$"`, the string would have to start with `a` then end. So `"a"` would match but `"aba"` wouldn't even though they both have a's.

Comment: Add-on, but related: how can you in R  specify your character class in a vector (like v <- c("a","b","c") ) ?

Comment: Quotes will create a character string automatically. What other classes were you interested in?

Comment: In case the character classes (the "allowed" chars) changes along-the-way, e.g. depending on function output. For some strings it may be "a" and "b" allowed, and others "b" and "e" (how can you put [ab] and [be] into a variable (does it make sense?)

Comment: I see. In that case you can use paste to combine the characters to look the same as the other pattern `my_pattern <- paste0("^[", v, "]+$")` and use that instead like `grep(my_pattern, s)`.