# Can I use regex with Stacks?

Tags: java, regex, stack

I am just now learning Stacks, Queues, and Deques, so this is all completely new to me.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511548/exclude-elements-from-vector-based-on-regular-expression-pattern) link explaining how to use regex with Vectors, but it's for the R language, and I'm having no luck finding any implementation of regex in Java with this class.

If I simply want to remove the brackets from a Stack, is this possible in Java?

I tried

```
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    stack.push("Item1");
    stack.push("Item2");
    stack.push("Item3");

    stack = stack.replaceAll(\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
```

however I get the compiler error

```
    method.java.util.Vector.replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)
    is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

So, I thought about how I could print each item in something such as an ArrayList without brackets without using regex, and I simply did a for each loop, like so:

```
    for(Object item : stack)
        System.out.print(item + " ");
```

which returns

```
    Item1 Item2 Item3
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The question is up there.

Comment: "If I simply want to remove the brackets from a Stack, is this possible in Java?"

Comment: Your items in stack don't even have `[` or `]`

Comment: Did you mean: `String tostr = stack.toString().replaceAll(\\[|\\]", "");`

Comment: Yes. I know the output doesn't show the brackets. That's because I looped through them. I was just wondering if regex was possible with Stacks, which I figured out. I was just experimenting with print statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no brackets actually in the stack. They are generated by its [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) method that is automatically called when you `println` the stack, so you would need to manually call that before performing the replacement on the generated string.

You don't actually need to use regex to do this plain string replacement. If you use [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), which is the non-regex version of `String.replaceAll`, you won't need to escape the brackets. (The `String.replaceAll` method is often used unnecessarily as it's very poorly named.)

```
System.out.print(theStack.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

However, you shouldn't use string replacement at all for this, as it will produce the wrong result if any items in the stack themselves contain brackets. You could hack your way around that by doing something like `str.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]\\z", "")` or `str.substring(1, str.length() - 1)` but it's messy, and still wouldn't match your manual loop in this case as it wouldn't remove the commas between items. So fudging around with the string is just wrong.

If you want to control the generated string, *the correct way to do it is to generate the string correctly in the first place*. E.g.:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Object item : stack) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(item);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

You can also use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) here, since all items in your stack are already strings. (`String.join` will produce an exception at runtime if any object in the collection is not a `String` or `CharSequence`.) You *should* specify the stack's item type when declaring it for better type safety. E.g.:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
/* ... add items ... */
System.out.println(String.join(" ", stack));
```

If not all the items are strings, you can map them to strings and join them together this way:

```
System.out.println(stack.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

P.S. [`java.util.Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) has been obsolete since Java 5 came out in 2004. In new code you should replace it with either an [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) or a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). All of the above code works the same with those classes, although they have other different features and performance characteristics.

Comment: I will definitely replace it. I guess it's just part of our curriculum to learn all the different collections.

Answer (score -1):

If I would have waited just a few more minutes before asking, I wouldn't have needed to post in the first place. I figured it out:

```
System.out.print(theStack.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", ""));
```